# How do count queries count towards quotas?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Suppose I perform a count on a ndb query.  e.g.

```
@classmethod
def num_bets_updated_in_last(cls, minutes=60):
    td = datetime.timedelta( minutes=minutes )
    dt_start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()-td
    return BetInfo.query( BetInfo.last_update>dt_start ).count()
```

How would these count towards my quotas https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore

Would it be a single read, a single operation, a number of reads equalling the count, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can activate [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) to get the count for you.

More info in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816879/can-any-one-explain-how-to-understanding-datastore-read-costs-in-app-engine).

Answer (score 1):

NDB's count simply fetches all entities and returns their total number. Note that this is very inefficient and doesn't scale well since counting a million entities would cost million reads(only if the query completes in under 60 seconds otherwise an exception would be raised).

As already mentioned, use [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) for more detailed information on costs.

Comment: That's partly true, but it's a bit more complicated than that. For simple queries not involving !=, NOT or OR operations, the counting is performed without fetching the entities from the datastore. But in the worst case, you're right, all entities are read and counted.